# Is there any function to make right align for numbers through out the Spreadsheet in app-script

Tags: google-apps-script

Does a function exist to right align numbers throughout a spreadsheet in Google Apps Script?

```js
var lastRow = sheetName.getDataRange().getLastRow();
var lastCol = sheetName.getDataRange().getLastColumn(); 
sheetName.getRange(1,1,lastRow,lastCol).setFontSize(12).setHorizontalAlignment("left").setFontFamily("Calibri");
```

Comment: Could you please describe with more detail what are you trying to accomplish? You shared a code snippet that sets the whole sheet to be aligned to the right. What relation does that have to your question? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick solution I just tried on a test Google spreadsheet.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var lastRow = range.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = range.getLastColumn();

  for ( rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < lastRow; rowIndex++ ) {
    for ( colIndex = 0; colIndex < lastColumn; colIndex++ ) {
      var val = (values[rowIndex][colIndex]);
      console.log(val);

      if (!isNaN(parseFloat(val))) {
        sheet.getRange(rowIndex+1, colIndex+1).setHorizontalAlignment('right');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, the process is this:

1. Get all the data values on the sheet.
2. Iterate through all the data now stored in the `values` variable
3. For each value (variable `val`), Check if it is a numeric value and if it is numeric, set the horizontal alignment to the right.